# HTML text in Crystal Report 2015

Tags: t-sql, crystal-reports

It is possible to dispay a HTML text from DB to Crystal report?

Now I have this text:

```
<b>EMOCROMOCITOMETRICO</b> IN DATA 10-12-2017 ESITO: ; : BC : 4.240; HGB : 11.000; MCV : 78.000;
PLT : 375.000; WBC : 8.800; NEU% : 56.300; LYM% : 34.700; MON% : 5.600; EOS% : 3.100; INR : 1.050;
```

I want to create a PDF file with Crystal report but I see the tag HTML instead of bold text.

It is possible to do this and how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it by changing the text interpretation to HTML.

Create a formula field and take the DB field into formula field and place it on the report.

```
Now Right Click formula field --> format ---> Paragraph --> text representation --> change to html
```

and click ok